# Oracle SQL Bring Multiple values using Instr

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this simple query:

```
select *
from My_table
where
INSTR('|' || NVL(:USER_AREA_ID, AREA_ID) || '|', '|' || AREA_ID || '|') > 0
```

So basically, when the user selects area id 20 for example, the result would be a select all from my_table where area_id equals 20. The | are there to avoid selecting area_ids number 2 and area_ids number 0. Which is good.
However, user will have the ability to select multiple area_ids.
For example, how can the user select area_id 20 and area_id 60 at the same time without selecting area_ids 2, 0 and 6?
Or select area_ids 72, 90 and 5 avoiding the selection of area_ids 7, 2, 9, 0 as well?

Thank you

Comment: Can you share some sample data from this column? Why not just `WHERE AREA_ID = :USER_AREA_ID`?  Is it pipe delimited data in each record?

Comment: With your score you should somehow realize that you ommited vital information about the data in the searched column which makes th aanswer impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:
select *
from my_table
WHERE
AREA_ID IN (
SELECT TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(NVL(:USER_AREA_ID, AREA_ID), '\d+', 1, LEVEL))
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(NVL(:USER_AREA_ID, AREA_ID), '\d+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
)